# Geopandas In AWS Lambda Layer "Importing the numpy C-extensions failed"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, geopandas, aws-lambda-layers

I'm currently trying to setup an aws lambda that will use geopandas. To do this, I've created a Lambda Layer with the necessary pip installs for the lambda. To do this, I created a docker image with:

```
FROM python:3.8
USER root

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yqq wget && apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk -yqq && apt-get install zip && apt-get --assume-yes install  curl

RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
    python3 -m pip install virtualenv
```

From there, I run the image with

> docker run -it image_name bash

Create a pandas environment

> python3.8 -m venv pandas

Then I pip install the necessary packages

```
bash> source pandas/bin/activate
(pandas) bash> pip install geopandas -t ./python
(pandas) bash> pip install sqlalchemy -t ./python
(pandas) bash> deactivate
bash> zip -r python.zip ./python/
```

Then I pull that python.zip

> docker cp image_name:python.zip ./Desktop/

From there I upload the zip file to an s3 location and reference that s3 saved file in the lambda layer. I then attach it to my lambda function, but then when I test the lambda, I run into this error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': Unable to import required dependencies:
    numpy: 
        IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!
        Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
        many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
        installed.
        
        We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:
        https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html
        
        Please note and check the following:
          * The Python version is: Python3.8 from \"/var/lang/bin/python3.8\"
          * The NumPy version is: \"1.19.4\"
        and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
        Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.
        Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
}
```

I've checked that the python and numpy version are correct, and they match what they should be. Is there something I've done fundamentally wrong for me to keep getting this error when testing my lambda?

Comment: Can you update with how you solved this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to download the specific library for your specific lambda python version, here [1] instead the pip one.

In me case numpy-1.19.5-**cp38**-cp38-**manylinux2010_x86_64**.whl then unzip that file and put the output library in your project. (**Python 3.8**)

[1] https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#files